# login issue Android studio SQLite

Tags: java, android, sqlite, authentication

I tried to apply login in my application but still I am getting error in inserting I have this method for login in database helper class:

```html
 public String StdLogin(String UserName) {

        Cursor cursor= db.query("StudentTbl",null,"UserName=?",new String[]{UserName},null,null,null);
        if(cursor.getCount()<1){

            cursor.close();
            return "Not EXIST";
        }
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        String password=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Password"));
        cursor.close();
        return password;

    }
```

and in my java file for the activity I have this method for checking the login details

```html
public void Login() {
        btnLogin.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        String Login = myDb.StdLogin(editName.getText().toString());
                        String password=EditPass.getText().toString();
                        if(Login==null)
                            Login="-1";
                        if(password==null)
                            password="-1";
                        if ( password.equals(Login))
                            Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Login Succesful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        else
                            Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Login Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
        );
    }
```

but I am still getting this error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'java.lang.String
>   com.example.university.universitycommunication.DataBaseHelper.StdLogin(java.lang.String)'
>   on a null object reference "

could anyone help me on that.

here is myDB

```html
public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final String DataBaseName="UniversityCommunication.db";
    public static final String TableName="Employee";
    public static final String Table1Name="Announcement";
    public static final String Table2Name="Student";
    public static final String Table3Name="Book";
    public static final String Table4Name="Recommendation";
    public static final String Col1="ID";
    public static final String Col2="Events";

    public DataBaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DataBaseName, null, 2);
    }
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("create table IF NOT EXISTS Employee(EmployeeID INTEGER Primary Key AUTOINCREMENT,EmployeeName TEXT,Email TEXT" +
                "Phone INTEGER,UserName TEXT,Password Text)");
        db.execSQL("create table IF NOT EXISTS Announcement(ID INTEGER Primary Key AUTOINCREMENT,EmployeeID INTEGER,Content TEXT,date DATE,time DATETIME0)");
        db.execSQL("create table  IF NOT EXISTS  TeacherApology(ID INTEGER Primary Key AUTOINCREMENT,EmployeeID INTEGER,Content TEXT,date DATE,time DATETIME0)");

      //  db.execSQL("create table Student(StudentID INTEGER Primary Key AUTOINCREMENT,StudentName TEXT,Email TEXT" +
       //         "Phone INTEGER,UserName TEXT,Password Text)");
        db.execSQL("create table  IF NOT EXISTS StudentTbl(StudentID INTEGER Primary Key AUTOINCREMENT,StudentName TEXT,Email TEXT" +
                "UserName TEXT,Password Text)");
        db.execSQL("create table  IF NOT EXISTS Recommendation(ID INTEGER Primary Key AUTOINCREMENT,Content TEXT)");
        db.execSQL("create table  IF NOT EXISTS Book(ID INTEGER Primary Key AUTOINCREMENT,ISBN INTEGER,Title TEXT,Author TEXT,Status INTEGER)");

    }
```

here is the calling of databasehelper

```html
 DataBaseHelper myDb;
    EditText editName,EditPass;
    Button btnLogin;
    Context context=this;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        editName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        EditPass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        Login();
    }
```

Comment: show us where myDb is defined please

Comment: I have added to the question

Comment: the error tell you that myDb object is not assigned can you show us where you make the instance of DataBaseHelper